# Rails and Dropbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, dropbox

Good day, I'm using gem 'rails', '3.2.12' and 
gem 'dropbox', :git => 'git://github.com/tonywok/dropbox.git', :branch => 'v1'
In my application. 
If i'll open console and do this thing:

```
@options = (YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root}/config/paperclipdropbox.yml")[Rails.env].symbolize_keys)
@dropbox_key = @options[:dropbox_key]
@dropbox_secret = @options[:dropbox_secret]
@dropboxsession = Dropbox::Session.new(@dropbox_key, @dropbox_secret)
  => #<Dropbox::Session 123123 (unauthorized)>
@dropboxsession.mode = :dropbox
@dropboxsession.authorize_url 
  => "https://www.dropbox.com/1/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=123123"
dropbox_session = @dropboxsession
dropbox_session.authorize
  => true
dropbox_session.upload("#{Rails.root}/config.ru", '/')
```

I get this:

```
Dropbox::UnsuccessfulResponseError: HTTP status Net::HTTPForbidden received: https://api-content.dropbox.com/1/files/dropbox
from /home/alexandr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/bundler/gems/dropbox-7d060d5932eb/lib/dropbox/api.rb:228:in `upload'
```

What did I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@dropboxsession.mode = :sandbox fixed it.
What means :sandbox and :dropbox ?
development and production?

Comment: that's most likely the case. i'm guessing sandbox doesn't save any file changes to your dropbox account?

Comment: @CourtS Yes, now I'm think so too.